# Is it possible to architect the web component tier in Java EE to support different client types?

Tags: jakarta-ee, client

How can you architect the web component tier in Java EE to support different client types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/web-tier/web-tier5.html

Section 4.4.2.2

(Obtained by pasting your question into Google.)